# Qt with OpenGL extensions and OpenCL

Tags: qt, opengl, opencl

Use Qt as my GUI library.

Now I need to use OpenGL with extensions and maybe with OpenCL. 
First of all I need to load OpenGL extensions.

In glextensions.cpp/glextensions.h (c:\QtSDK\Demos\4.7\boxes) it's done in such way:

```
#define RESOLVE_GL_FUNC(f) ok &= bool((f = (_gl##f) context->getProcAddress(QLatin1String("gl" #f))));  

RESOLVE_GL_FUNC(GenFramebuffersEXT);
```

Can you explain how it works?

Also I need to create special type of context to use OpenGL in conjuction with OpenCL.

Can I do it with QGLContext?

Comment: It's a macro that creates the necessary function pointers for the extensions you request.  Personally I'd just use GLEW, it's production proven and makes life easy.  For your second question you are going to have to post what makes your OpenCL context special, but remember Qt currently has no knowledge of OpenCL (not that Qt needs to for you to use it).

Comment: Since it is the CL context that needs to be *"special"* and not the GL context, there is absolutely no problem in interfacing OpenCL with a `QGLContext`, I've done that, too.

Comment: Qt includes FBOs, VBOs and a lot of other openGL extensions. Are you sure you explicitly need the extention?

Answer (score 1):

The QGLWidget class in Qt wraps all of the OpenGL extensions you are ever likely to need. Check these classes which wrap the relevant extensions:

- Frame buffers: [QGLFramebufferObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglframebufferobject.html)
- Pixel buffers: [QGLPixelBuffer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglpixelbuffer.html)
- GLSL shaders: [QGLShaderProgram](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglshaderprogram.html)

Start with Qt's [OpenGL examples here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-opengl.html).

To use OpenCL in this context check the [Qt teams blog post](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/04/07/using-opencl-with-qt/) and follow [these installation instructions here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/opencl-snapshot/). Works perfectly with Qt 4.8 on Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit).

Comment: *"The QGLWidget class in Qt wraps all of the OpenGL extensions you are ever likely to need."* - Sorry but while the Qt OpenGL classes are quite useful, that's just too general (not to say too narrow-minded) a statement to be true. What about VAOs, fragment shader output locations, or texture buffers (and those are just *some* not very unlikely extensions to need). As a side note nobody on earth would ever use a `QGLPixelBuffer`, anyway.